# How can I loop through 3 specific form inputs and set the readonly attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This works but I would like to use a jquery loop to do the work

```
function setAddNewUserFormReadonly() {
  var firstName = $("#UserData_Person_FirstName");
  var lastName = $("#UserData_Person_LastName");
    var email = $("#UserData_Person_EmailAddress");

    firstName.attr('readonly', 'true');
    lastName.attr('readonly', 'true');
    email.attr('readonly', 'true');
}
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: I'd start with `var elements = $("#UserData_Person_FirstName,#UserData_Person_LastName,m#UserData_Person_EmailAddress");`

Comment: Not sure why you'd want a loop for this, but look up the [`each()` method](https://api.jquery.com/each)

Comment: Why?  Do you actually need to?  You could write a loop to do something similar by using things like `data-` attributes and a simple `for` loop.  This would be far faster, more readable and have a dramatically smaller footprint.

Answer (score 0):

It is legitimate to add classes to elements specifically to be able to group them for ease of access in code. For example, you might give each of your  #UserData_Person_FirstName, #UserData_Person_LastName and #UserData_Person_EmailAddress elements a class of 'readonlytag'. You would not need any related css for this - it is just an additional label we have applied for convenience.

Now in your code you can use

```
$('.readonlytag').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('readonly', 'true');
})
```

to select the elements that have classes including 'readonlytag' and set the readonly attribute via a loop.